# How do I return SQL results in the scope of the parent function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe-brackets

I'm currently working on a brackets text-editor extension that keeps your work time in a database and lets you view your time entries. I'm using NodeJS to interact with the SQL server. I've been able to enter time as I want and I've successfully called the entries with a select statement. However, I am trying to display the results on a panel at the bottom of brackets.

I can't figure out how to get the result from my select statement to the wider scope so I can pass it to main.js. I'm new to Node and have read a lot about callbacks and promises but nothing seems to help. I tried using a callback but I can't get the value from the callback to equal a variable that can be returned.

UPDATE: The viewTime() function is returned to main.js as a promise. If I could name con.connect() as a regular function then I could call it in main.js through registerCommand (command handler function).

Here's the code:`

```
(function () {
"use strict";
var mysql = require('mysql');
/**
* @private
*
* @return {array}
*/

function viewTime() {
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "root",
        database: "brackets_timer_data"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Connected!");
      }
        con.query("SELECT * FROM work_sessions", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            //I need to get the result from here
         });
        });
      //And return it here so I can pass the variable to main.js
}

 /**
 * Initializes the test domain with several test commands.
 * @param {DomainManager} domainManager The DomainManager for the server
*/
    function init(domainManager) {
        if (!domainManager.hasDomain("view")) {
            domainManager.registerDomain("view", {major: 0, minor: 1});
        }
        domainManager.registerCommand(
            "view",       // domain name
            "viewTime",    // command name
            viewTime,   // command handler function
            false,          // this command is synchronous in Node
            "Returns time entry results.",
            [{}],
            [{name: "results", // return values
                type: "array",
              description: "Time entry results"}]
        );
    }
exports.init = init;

}());
```

`Any thoughts?

Comment: You can wrap `con.query` in Promise. Like `return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ 
con.query() });`

Comment: I've tried that. I'm able to get the results now using .then() but it only works inside of .then(). When I set it to a variable and try to log the result, it comes back as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise` and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to return the session details. First, you need to chain `Promise` and then return the session details. The calling function in `main.js` should be `async` to read the return values from the promised function.

Making those changes to your code,

```
"use strict";

let mysql = require('mysql');

function viewTime() {
  let con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "brackets_timer_data"
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.connect(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err while establishing connection ', err);
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log('Connected!');
      resolve();
    });
  }).then(() => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM work_sessions", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err in while fetching session details ', err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
      return Promise.resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

function init(domainManager) {

  // your other code

  viewTime().then(sessions => {
    domainManager.registerCommand(
      "view",       // domain name
      "viewTime",    // command name
      sessions,   // command handler function
      false,          // this command is synchronous in Node
      "Returns time entry results.",
      [{}],
      [{
        name: "results", // return values
        type: "array",
        description: "Time entry results"
      }]
    );
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('err in init()', err);
  });

}

exports.init = init;
```

Comment: I am getting an unexpected token function error. As far as calling the function in main.js with an async function, main.js isn't interpreted by node. Is this the problem?

Comment: @IsaacDew Could be. I've updated the code to use only promises

Comment: With this code I'm getting an "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined".

Comment: May be some other code causes it? Could you replace ()=>{} with function(){} and check